# Marshalling a complex structure from C# to C

Tags: c#, c, struct, marshalling, dllimport

I'm reading all about structure marshalling between C and C# in 64bit environment without success.

What I need to do is to pass the structure

```
typedef struct DescStructTa
{
    char*           pszNa;
    unsigned long   ulTId;      
    char*           pszT;
    unsigned short  usRId;
    unsigned long   ulOff;
    unsigned long   ulSi;
    char            szAcc[2];
    unsigned char   bySSize;
} DescStruct;
```

from a C# application to a C DLL not made by us calling the method

```
MT_DLL_DECL long GetAll(UINTPTR ulHandler, DescStruct **ppList, unsigned long *pulNumS);
```

After long search I wrote the following code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 8)]
    public struct PlcSymbolDescStruct
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        string pszNa;
        UInt32 ulTId;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        string pszT;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        ushort usRId;
        UInt32 ulOff;
        UInt32 ulSi;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 2)]
        string szAcc;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        byte bySSize;
    }

    [DllImport("DataSource.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)]public static extern long GetAll(ulong ulHandler, out DescStruct [] ppList,
         out uint pulNumS);
```

Unfortunately this is still giving me a heap corruption.
If I try to pack less than 8 it gives (as expected) an access violation, but I expected this to work and I'm not able to figure out what could be wrong.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might be worth looking at using managed C++ as an intermediary between C# and C. It's easier than trying to do it directly from C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not sure you need `Pack = 8`. The default packing appears to be more or less compatible between C# and C++.

The `szAcc` field probably uses Unicode. To switch, specify `CharSet=CharSet.Ansi` in your `[StructLayout]`

Finally, if your C API has that double pointer to the array of them, you have to allocate that memory in a special way, either CoTaskMemAlloc or LocalAlloc, forgot which one.
It’s easier, also more efficient, to implement 2 functions instead. One to obtain the required size of the array. Another one to write them into caller-allocated buffer, a single pointer in C++ as opposed to double pointer, and `UnmanagedType.LPArray` in C#.

**Update**

> allocation should not be necessary since the documentation states that the call returns a pointer to it's internal data structure

The runtime doesn’t know what was written in that documentation, attempts to free anyway, and crashes. You can use `out IntPtr` in C# API, and marshal manually.

If you have modern .NET, use unsafe, cast the IntPtr to `PlcSymbolDescStruct*` raw pointer, and construct `ReadOnlySpan<PlcSymbolDescStruct>` from that raw pointer.

if you’re stuck with old desktop .NET, call `Marshal.PtrToStructure<PlcSymbolDescStruct>` in a loop, incrementing the pointer by `Marshal.SizeOf<PlcSymbolDescStruct>()` bytes between loop iterations. No need to use unsafe code in this case.

Comment: I forgot to tell that this DLL is not made by us so we can't change the methods. I'll try the Unicode. Also the allocation should not be necessary since the documentation states that the call returns a pointer to it's internal data structure that must not be freed by the application.

Comment: If you want to use Unicode, don't set an  `Ansi` charset.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel The OP has `char` data type in the API of external library they can’t change.

Comment: Ah, okay, I misunderstood your answer, then.

Comment: @Soonts The solution of IntPtr and manually marshal worked like a charm. Thanks!